# Run Python code on AWS Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am searching for some simple way to develop Python scripts and run them on AWS EC2 instance.

What is the most preferable way ?

Answer (score 1):

EC2 is nothing but a remote server.
Once you launched it, you can do everything that is possible to do with any server.

The following guide describes how to launch your first EC2:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

After that, just upload your python scripts there and launch them.